# How to update JSONArray with new values?

Tags: java, json

The below is JSON object which is retrieved from database (input).

```
{"Pickup Date End":["{\"date\":\"2020-12-30T14:15:00\",\"tzId\":\"Asia/Calcutta\",\"tzCode\":\"IST\"}","{\"date\":\"2020-12-31T14:15:00\",\"tzId\":\"Asia/Calcutta\",\"tzCode\":\"IST\"}"],
"Pickup Date Start":["{\"date\":\"2020-12-30T14:15:00\",\"tzId\":\"Asia/Calcutta\",\"tzCode\":\"IST\"}","{\"date\":\"2020-12-31T14:15:00\",\"tzId\":\"Asia/Calcutta\",\"tzCode\":\"IST\"}"]}
```

I did some required customization (in *Pickup Date End* JSONObject) and tried to put updated values in the same JSONArray which as below (output)

```
{"Pickup Date End":[{"date":"2020-12-30T02:45:00","tzId":"Asia/Calcutta","tzCode":"IST"},{"date":"2020-12-31T02:45:00","tzId":"Asia/Calcutta","tzCode":"IST"}],"Pickup Date Start":["{"date":"2020-12-30T02:45:00","tzId":"Asia/Calcutta","tzCode":"IST"},{"date":"2020-12-31T02:45:00","tzId":"Asia/Calcutta","tzCode":"IST"}"]}
```

But this gives an error which may be due to \ is not present in updated JSONObject.
**Can someone please suggest how to apply escape i.e. \ character for JSONObjcet in Java?**

Code is

```
try {
      TimeZone siteTz = TimeZoneUtil.getSiteTimeZoneBySiteSysId(shipFromSiteId.longValue(), DvceContext.getInstanceAdminContext());
     if (changesObject != null) {
       JSONObject changes = (JSONObject) changesObject.get("Changes");
       if (changes.has("Pickup Date End")) {
         JSONArray valueArray = (JSONArray) changes.get("Pickup Date End");
         JSONObject oldJson = new JSONObject(valueArray.get(0).toString());
         JSONObject newJson = new JSONObject( valueArray.get(1).toString());
         
         Calendar oldCalendar = DateUtils.getFormattedDate((String) oldJson.get("date"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
         Calendar newCalendar = DateUtils.getFormattedDate((String) newJson.get("date"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");             
         oldCalendar = TimeZoneUtil.convertTimeToTimeZone(oldCalendar, siteTz);
         newCalendar = TimeZoneUtil.convertTimeToTimeZone(newCalendar, siteTz);
         
         DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
         dateFormat.setTimeZone(siteTz);
         
         oldJson.put("date", dateFormat.format(oldCalendar.getTime()));
         newJson.put("date", dateFormat.format(newCalendar.getTime()));
         JSONArray newValuesArray = new JSONArray();
         newValuesArray.put(0, oldJson);
         newValuesArray.put(1, newJson);
         changes.put("Pickup Date End", newValuesArray);
         changesObject.put("Changes", changes);
         //row.setValue(changesColIndex, changesObject.toString());
       }
     }          
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO either LOG the exception or re-throw, but not both
    }
```

Comment: You have put JSON objects into the array, while previously it were strings.

Comment: The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

Comment: Add your full code, what is `changes` variable datatype and input?

Comment: @Shakthifuture Please check now

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @Henry How do I convert updated JSON Object in string again which will contain escape characters?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code, I don't know what is your exact customization. I am changed your `oldJson` variable value for **sample**. I hope this will help you for further modification. Here's the code.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Calendar;

import org.apache.http.client.utils.DateUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONOp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
//          TimeZone siteTz = TimeZoneUtil.getSiteTimeZoneBySiteSysId(shipFromSiteId.longValue(),
//                  DvceContext.getInstanceAdminContext());
            JSONObject changesObject = new JSONObject("{\"Pickup Date End\":[\"{\\\"date\\\":\\\"2020-12-30T14:15:00\\\",\\\"tzId\\\":\\\"Asia/Calcutta\\\",\\\"tzCode\\\":\\\"IST\\\"}\",\"{\\\"date\\\":\\\"2020-12-31T14:15:00\\\",\\\"tzId\\\":\\\"Asia/Calcutta\\\",\\\"tzCode\\\":\\\"IST\\\"}\"],\r\n"
                    + "\"Pickup Date Start\":[\"{\\\"date\\\":\\\"2020-12-30T14:15:00\\\",\\\"tzId\\\":\\\"Asia/Calcutta\\\",\\\"tzCode\\\":\\\"IST\\\"}\",\"{\\\"date\\\":\\\"2020-12-31T14:15:00\\\",\\\"tzId\\\":\\\"Asia/Calcutta\\\",\\\"tzCode\\\":\\\"IST\\\"}\"]}");
            if (changesObject != null) {
                JSONObject changes = changesObject;
                if (changes.has("Pickup Date End")) {
                    JSONArray valueArray = (JSONArray) changes.get("Pickup Date End");
                    System.out.println("Before update: "+ valueArray);
                    JSONObject oldJson = new JSONObject(valueArray.get(0).toString());
                    JSONObject newJson = new JSONObject(valueArray.get(1).toString());
                    
                    //Start
                    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(oldJson.get("date").toString());
                    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    String formatDateTime = localDateTime.format(formatter);
                    //End
                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

                    oldJson.put("date", formatDateTime);
                    JSONArray newValuesArray = new JSONArray();
                    newValuesArray.put(0, oldJson);
                    newValuesArray.put(1, newJson);
                    changes.put("Pickup Date End", newValuesArray);
                    System.out.println("After update: "+ changes);
                    changesObject.put("Changes", changes);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO either LOG the exception or re-throw, but not both
        }

    }

}
```

**Output**:

```
Before update: ["{\"date\":\"2020-12-30T14:15:00\",\"tzId\":\"Asia/Calcutta\",\"tzCode\":\"IST\"}","{\"date\":\"2020-12-31T14:15:00\",\"tzId\":\"Asia/Calcutta\",\"tzCode\":\"IST\"}"]
After update: {"Pickup Date End":[{"date":"2020-12-30 14:15:00","tzId":"Asia/Calcutta","tzCode":"IST"},{"date":"2020-12-31T14:15:00","tzId":"Asia/Calcutta","tzCode":"IST"}],"Pickup Date Start":["{\"date\":\"2020-12-30T14:15:00\",\"tzId\":\"Asia/Calcutta\",\"tzCode\":\"IST\"}","{\"date\":\"2020-12-31T14:15:00\",\"tzId\":\"Asia/Calcutta\",\"tzCode\":\"IST\"}"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Able to solve this issue, below is solution.

```
newValuesArray.put(0, oldJson.toString());
newValuesArray.put(1, newJson.toString());
```